# Find string in row and copy whole column to new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find a column with a string of text and copy it into another sheet. The top row would contain text "Module Check" but might have other text after or before. I know that I can do the following if I know the exact string. How do I search for a string in the top row and then select the whole column based on that string?

```
Sub FinalAssignmentImportedtoCleaned()
   
    Sheets("Imported").Select
    Set MR = Range("A1:ZZ1")
    For Each Cell In MR
        If Cell.Value = "Module Check" Then Cell.EntireColumn.Copy
    Next
    Sheets("Cleaned").Select
    Range("D:D").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    [D1].Value = "Module Check"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Like` operator will match pattern of a string against the full string. That's useful when you want to use wildcard in your match.

So change `=` with `Like` and this code `If Cell.Value Like "*Module Check*" Then Cell.EntireColumn.Copy` should do the trick.

If you want to check if only word exist in the end of the sentence you can do  `"*Module Check"`

---

If you want to avoid case-sensitivity you can use `LCase$()`, i.e.

```
If LCase$(Cell.Value) Like LCase$("*Module Check*") Then Cell.EntireColumn.Copy
```

---

If you want to avoid select and make code more robust you could rewrite it a little bit:

```
Sub FinalAssignmentImportedtoCleaned()
    
    Dim lcol As Long
    Dim ws_copy As Worksheet 'Declare sheet to copy from
    Dim ws_paste As Worksheet 'Declare sheet to paste to

    Set ws_copy = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Imported") 'Set sheet name to copy from
    Set ws_paste = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Cleaned") 'Set sheet name to paste to
    
    lcol = ws_copy.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Find last column with data at row 1
    
    Set MR = ws_copy.Range(ws_copy.Cells(1, "A"), ws_copy.Cells(1, lcol))
    For Each Cell In MR
        If Cell.Value Like "*Module Check*" Then Cell.EntireColumn.Copy
    Next
    ws_paste.Range("D1").PasteSpecial
    ws_paste.Cells(1, "D").Value = "Module Check"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That did it!!! Wonderful. You're a life saver.

Comment: Thank you, glad it helped you! Happy coding :)!!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I do also wonder what I might do to edit this if I were to not know the exact range/number of columns in line "Set MR = ws_copy.Range("A1:zz1"

Comment: Sure :), only happy to help! I assume you will always start at column A (in row 1) but you can change that. We then check all the columns to the right of column A and try to find the last column with data. We store the column number in the variable: `lcol`. We will get a column number which we can use in the `Set MR = ws_copy.Range(....)`. Please see the updated code.